# How to make flat NSButton?

Tags: cocoa, nsbutton, nsbuttoncell

How can I make a flat `NSButton` just like in this picture?

[image: buttons]

I think this picture from Mac OS X >= 10.9. I have Mac OS X 10.8.5.

Comment: I suspect you may need to subclass `NSButtonCell`.  By the way, I think that picture is of an `NSSegmentedControl`, not `NSButton`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the border to your button.  In interface builder it is a simple check mark in the attributes inspector

Comment: Unchecking "bordered" removes the background too, so all you see is the text.  I don't think that's what the poster wants.